# How to scale Docker containers in production

Tags: scale, production, docker

So I recently discovered this awesome tool, and it says

> Docker is an open-source project to easily create lightweight,
>   portable, self-sufficient containers from any application. The same
>   container that a developer builds and tests on a laptop can run at
>   scale, in production, on VMs, bare metal, OpenStack clusters, public
>   clouds and more.

Let's say I have a docker image which runs Nginx and a website connects to external database. How do I scale the container in production?

Answer (score 599, accepted):

## Update: 2019-03-11

First of all thanks for those who have upvoted this answer over the years.

Please be aware that this question was asked in August 2013, when Docker was still a very new technology. Since then: [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) was launched on June 2014, [Docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) was integrated into the Docker engine in Feb 2015, Amazon launched it's [container solution, ECS,](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/04/amazon-ec2-container-service-is-now-generally-available/) in April 2015 and [Google launched GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) in August 2015. It's fair to say the production container landscape has changed substantially.

---

The short answer is that you'd have to write your own logic to do this.

I would expect this kind of feature to emerge from the following projects, built on top of docker, and designed to support applications in production:

- [flynn](https://flynn.io/)
- [deis](http://deis.io/)
- [coreos](http://coreos.com/)
- [Mesos](http://mesosphere.io/2013/09/26/docker-on-mesos/)

## Update 1

Another related project I recently discovered:

- [maestro](https://github.com/toscanini/maestro)

## Update 2

The latest release Openstack contains support for managing Docker containers:

- [Docker Openstack](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Docker)
- [Paas zone within OpenStack](http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2013/10/31/build-a-paas-zone-within-your-openstack-cloud/)

## Update 3

System for managing Docker instances

- [Shipyard](http://shipyard-project.com/)

And a presentation on how to use tools like [Packer](http://www.packer.io/), Docker and [Serf](http://www.serfdom.io/) to deliver an immutable server infrastructure pattern

- [FutureOps with Immutable Infrastructure](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/12/futureops)
- [Slides](http://www.slideshare.net/profyclub_ru/8-mitchell-hashimoto-hashicorp)

## Update 4

A neat article on how to wire together docker containers using [serf](http://www.serfdom.io/):

- [Decentralizing Docker: How to use serf with Docker](http://www.centurylinklabs.com/decentralizing-docker-how-to-use-serf-with-docker/)

## Update 5

Run Docker on [Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/) using the [Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon) framework

[Mesosphere Docker Developer Tutorial](https://mesosphere.io/learn/run-docker-on-mesosphere-cluster/)

## Update 6

Run Docker on [Tsuru](http://www.tsuru.io) as it supports [docker-cluster](https://github.com/tsuru/docker-cluster) and [segregated scheduler deploy](http://docs.tsuru.io/en/latest/provisioners/docker/schedulers.html)

- http://blog.tsuru.io/2014/04/04/running-tsuru-in-production-scaling-and-segregating-docker-containers/

## Update 7

Docker-based environments orchestration

[maestro-ng](https://github.com/signalfuse/maestro-ng)

## Update 8

[decking.io](http://decking.io/)

## Update 9

Google [kubernetes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes)

## Update 10

Redhat have refactored their openshift PAAS to integrate Docker

- [Project Atomic](http://www.projectatomic.io/)
- [Geard](http://openshift.github.io/geard/)

## Update 11

A Docker NodeJS lib wrapping the Docker command line and managing it from a json file.

- [docker-cmd](https://github.com/iorga-group/docker-cmd)

## Update 12

Amazon's new [container service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/details/) enables scaling in the cluster.

## Update 13

Strictly speaking [Flocker](https://github.com/ClusterHQ/flocker) does not "scale" applications, but it is designed to fufil a related function of making stateful containers (running databases services?) portable across multiple docker hosts:

https://clusterhq.com/

## Update 14

A project to create portable templates that describe Docker applications:

http://panamax.io/

## Update 15

The Docker project is now addressing orchestration natively (See [announcement](https://blog.docker.com/2015/02/orchestrating-docker-with-machine-swarm-and-compose/))

- [Docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)
- [Docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/)
- [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

## Update 16

[Spotify Helios](https://github.com/spotify/helios)

See also:

- https://blog.docker.com/tag/helios/

## Update 17

The Openstack project now has a new "container as a service" project called Magnum:

- https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Magnum

Shows a lot of promise, enables the easy setup of Docker orchestration frameworks like Kubernetes and Docker swarm.

## Update 18

Rancher is a project that is maturing rapidly

http://rancher.com/

Nice UI and strong focus on hyrbrid Docker infrastructures

## Update 19

The [Lattice project](http://lattice.cf/) is an offshoot of Cloud Foundry for managing container clusters.

## Update 20

Docker recently bought Tutum:

https://www.docker.com/tutum

## Update 21

Package manager for applications deployed on [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/).

http://helm.sh/

## Update 22

Vamp is an open source and self-hosted platform for managing (micro)service oriented architectures that rely on container technology.

http://vamp.io/

## Update 23

A Distributed, Highly Available, Datacenter-Aware Scheduler

- https://www.nomadproject.io/

From the guys that gave us Vagrant and other powerful tools.

## Update 24

Container hosting solution for AWS, open source and based on [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/)

https://supergiant.io/

## Update 25

Apache Mesos based container hosted located in Germany

https://sloppy.io/features/#features

And Docker Inc. also provide a container hosting service called Docker cloud

https://cloud.docker.com/

## Update 26

[Jelastic](https://jelastic.com/blog/docker-swarm-auto-clustering-and-scaling-with-paas/) is a hosted PAAS service that scales containers automatically.

Comment: openstack is another candidate for this list

Comment: @benschwartz Very true, but only in the latest release.

Comment: @ElGamed Seen it, but haven't used it. Added to the list, thx!

Comment: @MarkO'Connor The `mesosphere/mesos-docker` project has been deprecated and replaced by `mesosphere/deimos`: https://github.com/mesosphere/deimos

Comment: Also worth looking at, from Google - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes

Comment: @MarkO'Connor The Mesosphere/deimos has been deprecated and Docker support is built into the core of Mesos.

Comment: @Ken Ah yes, thx for the update. I have updated the Docker tutorial link as well based on the 0.20.0 release of Mesos.

Comment: There's now https://github.com/iorga-group/docker-cmd inspired by decking.io but with a pure docker DSL

Comment: update 4 link is out of date, here is new one
http://www.centurylinklabs.com/decentralizing-docker-how-to-use-serf-with-docker/

Comment: Still waiting for the 'state-of-the-art' project :-/

Comment: Shipyard is cool, but not up-to-date. It's currently not supporting volume mapping and container linking, also it does not support template tools (like docker compose). So if you're slightly changing your docker container configuration (aka Dockerfile) you have to enter aaall details in the webmask again.

Comment: @derFunk This is an old answer now and Docker is moving fast. At the time Shipyard was amazing, now I'd recommend checking out Rancher which has container linking and load balancing.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've been researching alternatives the past weeks but didn't come across Rancher. Will give it a try (also they should improve their SEO :))

Comment: I'd add http://lattice.cf which is rapidly evolving towards 1.0, its the child of cloud foundry and enables scalable, highly available, load balanced docker workloads  - similar to kubernetes

Comment: Worth mentioning tutum here now?

Comment: @Omega Certainly now that tutum are intending to offer it as a private cloud option.

Comment: No love for HashiCorp's Nomad? :)

Comment: Did anyone mention docker services? Once a service is defined in a swarm, scaling is as simple as adding new hosts for resource additions and changing the replica count for container scale

Comment: @Dockstar Added mention of Docker cloud as you suggested

Comment: Jelastic PaaS should be added, as it provides automatic scaling for containers https://jelastic.com/blog/docker-swarm-auto-clustering-and-scaling-with-paas/

Answer (score 42):

[Deis](http://deis.io/) automates scaling of Docker containers (among other things).

Deis (pronounced DAY-iss) is an open source PaaS that makes it easy to deploy and manage applications on your own servers. Deis builds upon [Docker](http://docker.io/) and [CoreOS](http://coreos.com/) to provide a lightweight PaaS with a Heroku-inspired workflow.

Here is the developer workflow:

```
deis create myapp                      # create a new deis app called "myapp"
git push deis master                   # built with a buildpack or dockerfile
deis scale web=16 worker=4             # scale up docker containers
```

Deis automatically deploys your Docker containers across a CoreOS cluster and configures the Nginx routers to route requests to healthy Docker containers.  If a host dies, containers are automatically restarted on another host in seconds.  Just browse to the proxy URL or use `deis open` to hit your app.

Some other useful commands:

```
deis config:set DATABASE_URL=          # attach to a database w/ an envvar
deis run make test                     # run ephemeral containers for one-off tasks
deis logs                              # get aggregated logs for troubleshooting
deis rollback v23                      # rollback to a prior release
```

To see this in action, check out the terminal video at http://deis.io/overview/.  You can also [learn about Deis concepts](http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/understanding_deis/concepts/) or jump right into [deploying your own private PaaS](http://deis.io/get-deis/).

Comment: +1 I'm watching your project with interest. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 19):

You can try Tsuru. Tsuru is a opensource PaaS inspired in Heroku, and it is already with some products in production at Globo.com(internet arm of the biggest Broadcast Television Company in Brazil)

It manages the entire flow of an application, since the container creation, deploy, routing(with hipache) with many nice features as docker cluster, scaling of units, segregated deploy, etc.

Take a look in our documentation bellow:
http://docs.tsuru.io/

Here our post covering our environment:
http://blog.tsuru.io/2014/04/04/running-tsuru-in-production-scaling-and-segregating-docker-containers/

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at [Rancher.com](http://rancher.com/) - it can manage multiple Docker hosts and much more.

Comment: Rancher is open source, and includes a full distribution of Kubernetes. It provides a platform for running many different clusters, managing infrastructure and dramatically simplifies running containers.

Comment: Rancher is a great tool, I have managed clusters hosted on openstack. RKE UI is simple and powerful.

Answer (score 9):

A sensible approach to scaling Docker could be:

1. Each service will be a **docker** container
2. Intra container service discovery managed through links ([new feature from docker 0.6.5](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_links_names/#links-service-discovery-for-docker))
3. Containers will be deployed through [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku)
4. Applications will be managed through [Shipyard](https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard) which in its turn is using [hipache](https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache)

Another docker open sourced project from Yandex:

- [cocaine](https://github.com/cocaine)

Comment: Can you provide any more advice on how to use Dokku alongside Shipyard?

Comment: This link is dead -- http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_links_names/#links-service-discovery-for-docker

Answer (score 2):

Openshift guys also created a project. You can find more information [here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/geard-the-intersection-of-paas-docker-and-project-atomic), try [test container](https://index.docker.io/u/ccoleman/geard/) and detailed info [here](http://openshift.github.io/geard/) .
The only problem is the solution is Redhat centric for now :)

Answer (score 2):

While we're big fans of Deis (deis.io) and are actively deploying to it, there are other Heroku like PaaS style deployment solutions out there, including:

Longshoreman from the Wayfinder folks:

https://github.com/longshoreman/longshoreman

Decker from the CloudCredo folks, using CloudFoundry:

http://www.cloudcredo.com/decker-docker-cloud-foundry/

As for straight up orchestration, NewRelic's opensource Centurion project seems quite promising:

https://github.com/newrelic/centurion

Answer (score 1):

Take a look also at [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) and [Consul](http://www.consul.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Panamax: Docker Management for Humans. [panamax.io](http://panamax.io)

Fig: Fast, isolated development environments using Docker. [fig.sh](http://www.fig.sh)

Comment: I think Fig do not yet support multi-host deployment.

Comment: Is that so! So it just helps orchestrate setting up of applications inside of a single host?

Answer (score 1):

One option not mentioned in other posts is Helios. It is built by spotify and does not try to do too much.

https://github.com/spotify/helios