# How to deploy multi-tier application using Docker?

Tags: virtualization, docker

Is there a way to deploy a multi-tier application using Docker? Does it have VMware vApp equivalent?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285212/how-to-scale-docker-containers-in-production/18287169#18287169

Comment: Another interesting posting: http://jipiboily.com/2013/install-dokku-postgresql-with-docker-for-your-rails-app-or-whatever-else-almost

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found so far to do this kind of multi-containers deployment is by using Fig (http://orchardup.github.io/fig/).

It may not be as featureful as vApp, but it's an easy way to manage containers as an environment.