# Docker Orchestration Tools

Tags: docker

Among these docker orchestration tools which all supports Configuration Deployment

Ansible,
Panama,
Shipyard,
Centurion,
Fig,
Puppet with Docker module,
Serf,
DEIS,
Kubernetes,
Scalr,
Flynn,
Dokku.

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Need to create a list of docker orchestration tool and its specifications like,
Management GUI,Application Deployment,Docker Deployment Configuration Deployment,Dynamic Deployment based
on available ressources,CLI Interface,Monitoring/Dashboard View Agent installation required,Support multiple hosting platforms
 (AWS, Dedicated Server etc)",Open Source Version 
available"

Comment: I dont have great knowledge about docker orchestration tools and its features.Need to create a spread sheet document stating wheather these  features supports the respective docker orchestration tools

Comment: @SHRI You should do your own research. But I would say you're missing CoreOS + fleet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scale Docker containers in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285212/how-to-scale-docker-containers-in-production)

Answer (score 3):

Rancher from [Rancher Labs](http://rancher.com) maybe worth looking at. Rancher is a simple to use docker orchestration technology.

It has a beautiful management UI.
 [image: rancher management ui]

Rancher does load balancing, service discovery, storage, clustering, networking and whole bunch of other things for docker containers. It is open source (http://github.com/rancherio)

It can do deployment based on available resources, the cli interface is the default docker cli itself!

It has monitoring capabilities and comes inbuilt with platform support for digital ocean, AWS, GCE, Azure, Vultr, vCloudAir and others will be added if not already present.

Disclaimer : I build rancher.