# Best tool for SQL Server database comparisons

Tags: sql-server, database, migration, comparison

I am migrating from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2014 via SQL Server 2008. I have transferred all the databases from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2014.

Now I need a tool to compare the both databases whether there is any change or not. The tool should visualize all the changes or differences between the source and target server databases.

Could anyone suggest me which tool would be the best option for that?

Comment: Stack Overflow states: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. "

Comment: Personally, I feel that answers that ask a very specific question about tools is fine.  Look at this very popular Docker question asking which tool to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285212/how-to-scale-docker-containers-in-production.  132 upvotes as of right now and basically asking "which tool to use to scale docker in production".

Answer (score 2):

There are no BEST tools. However you can use SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools) from Microsoft to easily compare the databases.
Another option is Red Gate Compare. However it costs a bit of money.

Comment: Is Red Gate Compare better than SSDT ?

Comment: I do not know what does it mean "better". But I can assume that SSDT will be good enough for you.

Comment: can SSDT be used without visual studio ?

Answer (score -1):

Afaik, no perfect solution exists. But to create a diff of the ordinary database citizens, like tables, indexes, constraints and such, i like to use liquibase. From their [website](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html):

```
liquibase.sh --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
    --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@testdb:1521:test \
    --username=bob \
    --password=bob \
    diff \
    --referenceUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE \
    --referenceUsername=bob \
    --referencePassword=bob
```

The example is for oracle, but liquibase can be used with any database you can find a JDBC connector for.

Comment: liquibase compares much less objects than SSDT or Red Gate.

Comment: @Wallenborn OS is using SQL Server not using ORACLE

Comment: The example is for oracle, but liquibase can be used with any database you can find a JDBC connector for.