# Enterprise Apps with Docker and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to `Docker` and `EB` but not `AWS`. I've worked in environments where dedicated tenancy is a requirement, whether due to HIPPA or some other data protection requirements.

So far as I can tell, in order to deploy a Docker image, you must use Beanstalk, which means you aren't able to have a dedicated tenancy.  I found this forum [question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=667589) that says if you create a VPC, you can have a dedicated Beanstalk.  Is this correct?  If so, will it work with Docker? If so any guides would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Amazon's ECS service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/)? It is a Docker container service that doesn't use Elastic Beanstalk.

You can also [install Docker on any EC2 instance](https://docs.docker.com/installation/amazon/).

If you use a VPC then you can set the default tenancy to dedicated, which will result in dedicated tenancy instances being created by Beanstalk. You should be using a VPC already if you are concerned with HIPAA compliance, or if you want access to pretty much any of the new features released by Amazon in the last year.

Also, `EBS` stands for Elastic Block Storage, Elastic Beanstalk is usually abbreviated `EB`.

Comment: It looks like this is the way to go.  I will gladly accept that answer once I get it up and running.  I walked through the custom ECS wizard and saw how to define containers and volumes.  Once I create a docker image and upload it to the hub and get it all working, I will accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to venture a bit more, you can also use other tools like

1. [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/)
2. [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/)
3. [RancherOS](http://rancher.com/rancher-os/)

For a more comprehensive list of Docker/Container related projects you can see this post:

[How to scale Docker containers in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285212/how-to-scale-docker-containers-in-production/18287169#18287169)

You can run them all in EC2 with VPC, also using dedicated tenancy if you'd like to.