# Horizontally scalable RESTful services?

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture

Lately I see this buzzword phrase in job requirements in position descriptions of skills needed from an applicant (knowledge of):
"Horizontally scalable RESTful services"...
What exactly is it? I cannot google anything that would really explain the notion.

Answer (score 3):

I expect that `horizontal scaling` is adding more servers to handle more load, rather than adding more memory and cpus to a server, as that is `vertical scaling`.

So, you could have a docker container that has your REST service, which should be [stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130036/how-to-understand-restful-api-is-stateless). There are many ways to scale in [production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285212/how-to-scale-docker-containers-in-production).

On each connection you could then create a new container, and once that service is done you remove it, so every connection has its own server.

If you are running something like nodejs, which is very light, then you could get away with this, but if you are using a heavier web server then you may want to look at something like [autoscaling](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/autoscaling/), from AWS, and as the load on each container goes up, create a new one, so you don't overload any particular server.

You don't have to use Docker, but it wouldn't hurt for you to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

running multiple instance of application in multiple machines with a  load balancer, We traditionally call it as web farming.

Answer (score 0):

If your API is stateless, then you can directly go to load balancer without docker.