# Docker Portable deployment across machines: where to start

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, docker, deployment

I need to install a new linux server on a vps, for using mysql, apache, php and some php appications.
In the future i might need to move this server to an other machine ( for example when i want to move the vps to a machine of my own in collocation).

I understand that with Docker, it is possible to just copy to whole server installation to another machine, without the need to reinstall everything.

But what is the most easy way to do this? What action do i need to when installing the new server? I guess i need to install Linux and the rest in a Docker installation. But i am not sure. Does anyone know a step by step guide?

I am new to Docker.  I get overwhelmed with all the tools on [How to scale Docker containers in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285212/how-to-scale-docker-containers-in-production/18287169#18287169).
I want to use Plesk as well. Plesk supports Docker. Perhaps is  that an easy way to go.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create Dockerfile in which you describe actions that you need to do on image, you can find examples in offical documentation https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

2) Build image from Dockerfile

3) Register on docker hub

4) Push your image to docker hub

5) When you setup new server you just need to pull your image from hub